# Common Lisp idiom for filtering a list and applying a function to the unfiltered elements?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, idioms

What is the Common Lisp idiom for this:

> Remove the elements in a list that don't satisfy a predicate and for
>   those that do satisfy the predicate apply a function.

Is this the Common Lisp idiom:

```
mapcar applied to remove-if
```

Comment: yes it is mapcar over remove-if

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiom would be [`MAPCAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) over [`REMOVE-IF-NOT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm), since you want to keep elements that match the predicate. The `-IF-NOT` functions are deprecated according to the standard, but for Common Lisp deprecation is mostly meaningless<sup>**1**</sup> and as such we rarely see anyone use [`COMPLEMENT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_comple.htm) with [`REMOVE-IF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm).

However most people would use a [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) here:

```
(lambda (elements test function)
  (loop
    for e in elements
    when (funcall test e)
      collect (funcall function e)))
```

A possible problem with [`MAPCAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) over [`REMOVE-IF-NOT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) is that it is going to allocate memory for a temporary list just to discard it after. You can call this premature optimisation, but if I wanted to use higher-order functions (e.g. because I want to work with generalised sequences instead of just lists), I would use [`MAP-INTO`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_map_in.htm):

```
(lambda (elements test function)
  (let ((tmp (remove-if-not test elements)))
    (map-into tmp function tmp)))
```

<sub>**1.** "*Everything that has been marked as deprecated can be considered un-deprecated since there won't be another standard.*", [R. Strandh (beach)](http://ircbrowse.net/browse/lisp?id=9368980&timestamp=1447481572#t1447481572).</sub>

Comment: ＋1 for mentioning the underappreciated **map-into**.